# Question about of Fatou's lemma in Rick Durrett's book.

Tags: probability-theory

In *Probability Theory and Examples*, Theorem $1.5.4$, Fatou's Lemma, says

> If $f_n \ge 0$ then
>   $$\liminf_{n \to \infty} \int f_n d\mu \ge \int \left(\liminf_{n \to \infty} f_n \right) d\mu. $$

In the proof, the author says

> Let $E_m \uparrow \Omega$ be sets of finite measure.

I'm confused, as without any information on the measure $\mu$, how can we guarantee this kind of sequence of events must exist?  Has the author missed some additional condition on $\mu$?

Comment: Assuming $m$ integers, such sets exists if and only if the measure is $\sigma$-finite.

Comment: Correct, this would be $\sigma$-finiteness, but it is not needed for the proof of Fatou's lemma. I don't own Durrett's book, so I don't know exactly what he is doing there.

Comment: I'm reading this copy of his book : http://stat-www.berkeley.edu/~aldous/205A/PTE4_Jan2010.pdf  The proof is on page 22.

Comment: At the very beginning of section 1.4 where Durrett defines the integral he assumes that the measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, so I guess it is a standing assumption about all integrals in this book that the underlying measure satisfies this. I am not sure why he does this, but since it is a probability book, he mostly deals with finite measures anyway, so I guess it is not a big problem in the context.

Comment: @LukasGeyer You can turn your comment in an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

At the beginning of section 1.4 where Durrett defines the integral he assumes that the measure $\mu$ is $\sigma$-finite, so I guess it is a standing assumption about all integrals in this book that the underlying measure satisfies this. Remember that it is a probability book, so his main interest are finite measures.